# Loading Translation Files from a Server or CMS in next-intl - Seeking Guidance

Tags: next.js, translation, i18next, next-intl

I'm looking for a solution to load translation files directly from a server or a Content Management System (CMS) in next-intl, rather than relying on local translation files. Currently, the documentation recommends importing translation files from the messages directory, as demonstrated in this code snippet:

i18n.ts

```js
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';
 
export default getRequestConfig(async ({locale}) => ({
  messages: (await import(`./messages/${locale}.json`)).default
}));
```

However, this approach poses challenges when it comes to correcting translation errors or making updates since it requires changes to project files and website redeployment. Is there a method to fetch translations directly from the server or a CMS? I've seen videos mentioning this capability, but I haven't found any relevant documentation.

I attempted the following approach, but it didn't yield the desired results:

```js
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';
 
export default getRequestConfig(async ({locale}) => ({

    messages: (fetch(`apiendpoint/${locale}`).then(res => res.json()).then(res => res.data)
    )

}));
```

Could someone please provide guidance on how to load translations from a server in next-intl, or point me in the right direction if there's documentation or resources available for this specific feature? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing well, but you forgot to `await` the promise.

### Your code:

```js
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';
 
export default getRequestConfig(async ({locale}) => ({
    messages: (fetch(`apiendpoint/${locale}`).then(res => res.json()).then(res => res.data)
    )
}));
```

Not the right side type (`(fetch(`apiendpoint/${locale}`).then(res => res.json()).then(res => res.data)`) is `Promise<any>` but `messages` expect to receive `IntlMessages`.

Try this instead:

```js
export default getRequestConfig(async ({locale}) => ({

    messages: (await fetch(`apiendpoint/${locale}`).then(res => res.json()).then(res => res.data)
    )
}));
```

This code looks unorganized, so let's format it:

```js
export default getRequestConfig(async ({locale}) => {
    const res = await fetch(endpoint)
    const data = await res.json()
    // Now, (data) is the json data returned from the api
    // try to console.log it to see if it contains data.data
    const messages = data.data
    
    return {
       messages
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I had added 'await' before, but I removed it since the response was the same. The problem for me was the API endpoint I was using. After some debugging, I found that there was no data inside the response. I am marking this as accepted because this solution is correct, better formatted, and may help someone. I'm currently facing an issue where Next.js isn't switching locales when making API calls, it is stuck on 'en' even though I am switching to 'ar'.

Comment: The problem is fixed now. The issue for me was that I was using the 'src' directory, whereas in the documentation, they do not use the 'src' folder. Inside the documentation, they store the middleware file in the root directory, which was causing errors for me because I was using the 'src' directory. If anyone else is encountering the same problem, simply save the middleware file in the 'src' directory.

Comment: You're right. The middleware must be as level as the `app` directory.